# How to remove "dissolution chamber: 100%" from HUD?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-mods

I'm playing the All The Mods 6 modpack, version 1.6.14. It contains Industrial Foregoing. When I built a Dissolution Chamber from Industial Foregoing, some text appeared on the right side of my HUD that says "Dissolution Chamber: 100%". This hasn't gone away for a hundred or so hours, no matter what I'm doing.

Any ideas how to stop that from showing?

[image]